# Custom Post Type "Event" with custom permalink structure

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I need some help about Custom permalinks for custom post types.

I have created a custom post type called "evento" and 3 custom fields for storing date, month and year of the events.

I would like to have a permalinks structure like this:

```
/eventos/2012/07/30
```

... where the standard structure would be:

```
/?post_type=evento&ano=2012&mes=07&dia=30
```

How to make this magic happen in WordPress? I do not know much about .Htaccess =(

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you searched the site? Resp. [tag:rewrite-rules], [tag:url-rewriting] and [tag:htaccess]?

Comment: Yes, but found nothing very explanatory or that I could understand. Thank you.

Comment: Please add what you've already tried so far and show us your research effort. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser How could I fix my pagination issue?

Comment: Please add this as solution (you can mark it as answer in two days). Then go and open a follow up question about your pagination issue (link in there to this question). One question per question :)

Comment: A sidenote/hint: If you write code in english (for e.g. "events" instead of "evento"), then it will be always much easier if you're searching for help, as everyone will be able to read it and understand what it's about. The same goes for commenting.

Comment: the problem was solved! Thannks!

Comment: As I said: Please add this as **answer**.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!!!! =)

```
add_action('init', 'evento_add_rewrite_rules');
function evento_add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ){
    // Add day archive (and pagination)
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]&dia=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]&dia=$matches[3]','top');

    // Add month archive (and pagination)
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&mes=$matches[2]','top');

    // Add year archive (and pagination)
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule("eventos/([0-9]{4})/?",'index.php?post_type=evento&ano=$matches[1]','top');
}
```